# What would be the optimal to parse XML files into objects? (Java)

Tags: java, xml

I'm making a simple JavaFX application to make a table for data analysis of BLASTP outputs in XML format. It isn't incredibly slow but I just want to make the program as efficient as I can. I added the code cut down a lot because the real files are quite large but they convey the general outline. I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me just suggestions for when I have to load a large amount of xmls like take a look at this api or try loading files into this object. The xml to table is as follows:

**Gather files from FileChooser**

```
public void listChange() throws //ALLEXCEPTIONS// {
    List<File> files = fc.showOpenMultipleDialog(new Stage());
    if (files != null) {
        files.forEach(f -> {
            try {
                xmlDataList.add(XMLFile(f.getPath()));
            } catch (//ALLEXCEPTIONS//) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Run the files through a SAX parser into object XMLDATA**

```
public XMLData XMLFile(String path) throws //ALLEXCEPTIONS// {
    if (path.endsWith(".xml")) {
        SAXParserFactory parserFactor = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXHandler saxh = new SAXHandler();
        SAXParser parser = parserFactor.newSAXParser();
        parser.parse(path, saxh);
        int suffix = 1;
        String pname = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\")+1, path.length() - 4), temp = pname;
        ArrayList<String> xmldataname = new ArrayList<>();
        xmlDataArrayListist.forEach(x -> xmldataname.add(x.pName));
        System.out.println("Finished");
        return new XMLData(saxh.hitList, temp);
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

**SAX handler creates a list of objects called HSPS(High Scoring Protein Sequences) and within that object is another object HSP(High Scoring Protein).**

```
public class SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    public ArrayList<HSPS> hitList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void startElement(String u, String ln, String ele, Attributes at)
            throws SAXException {
        switch(ele){
            case "Hit":
                hsps = new HSPS();
                break;
            case "Hsp":
                hsp = new HSP();
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String ln,String ele) throws SAXException {
        switch(ele){
            case "Hit_hsps":
                hitList.add(hsps);
                break;
            case "Hsp":
                hsps.hspL.add(hsp);
                break;
            case "Hit_def":
                hsps.name = content;
                break;
            case "Hit_id":
                hsps.id = content;
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        content = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length);
    }

}
```

The object HSPS contains the list of HSP and the name of the protein these sequences belong to. The HSP object contains a number of strings with data. 
The table simply reads all the HSP within the HSPS within the XMLFile object.

So after all that I guess my question is, was this the optimal way to transfer the correct items to the table? The xml files contain good amount more data but I only want a few items. If any addition information is needed just ask.

I have no experience with concurrence but if it will increase efficiency, I'll look into it.

Comment: Have you considered using something like [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have not, I'll look into it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try simple-xml very simple as name suggested.
```

**Maven dependency**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Sample Code**

```
 package com.vibhs.stack.overflow.xml;

 import java.io.File;
 import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
 import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

 public class Parser {

  private Serializer serializer = new Persister();

  public void createXML(Object object, File destination) throws Exception {

     serializer.write(object, destination);

   }

  public Object readXML(Class<?> clazz, File source) throws Exception {

    return serializer.read(clazz, source);

  }

 }
```